# Problem with return calculations using "tq_mutate" function in R

Tags: r, return, stock

I try to calculate stock returns for different time periods for a very large dataset.
I noticed that there are some inconsistencies with tq_mutate calculations and my checking:

```
library(tidyquant)
A_stock_prices  <- tq_get("A",
                       get  = "stock.prices",
                       from = "2000-01-01",
                       to   = "2004-12-31")

print(A_stock_prices[A_stock_prices$date>"2000-12-31",])
# A tibble: 1,003 x 8
   symbol date        open  high   low close  volume adjusted
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 A      2001-01-02  38.5  38.5  35.1  36.4 2261684     **31.0**
 2 A      2001-01-03  35.1  40.4  34.0  40.1 4502678     34.2
 3 A      2001-01-04  40.7  42.7  39.6  41.7 4398388     35.4
 4 A      2001-01-05  41.0  41.7  38.3  39.4 3277052     33.5
 5 A      2001-01-08  38.8  39.9  37.4  38.1 2273288     32.4
 6 A      2001-01-09  38.3  39.3  37.1  37.9 2474180     32.3
 ...
 1 A      2001-12-21  19.7  20.2  19.7  20.0 3732520     17.0
 2 A      2001-12-24  20.4  20.5  20.1  20.4 1246177     17.3
 3 A      2001-12-26  20.5  20.7  20.1  20.1 2467051     17.1
 4 A      2001-12-27  20.0  20.7  20.0  20.6 1909948     17.5
 5 A      2001-12-28  20.7  20.9  20.4  20.7 1600430     17.6
 6 A      2001-12-31  20.5  20.8  20.4  20.4 2142016     **17.3**

  A_stock_prices %>% 
       tq_transmute (select     = adjusted, 
                     mutate_fun = periodReturn, 
                     period     = "yearly") %>% 
       ungroup()

    # A tibble: 5 x 2
  date       yearly.returns
  <date>              <dbl>
1 2000-12-29         -0.240
2 2001-12-31         -0.479
3 2002-12-31         -0.370
4 2003-12-31          0.628
5 2004-12-30         -0.176
```

Now, based on the calculation, the yearly return for the year 2001 is: `"-0.479"`
But, when I calculate the yearly return myself (the close price at the end of the period divided by the close price at the beginning of the period), I get a different result:

```
A_stock_prices[A_stock_prices$date=="2001-12-31",]$adjusted/
A_stock_prices[A_stock_prices$date=="2001-01-02",]$adjusted-1

"-0.439"
```

Same issue persists with other time periods (e.g., monthly or weekly calculations).

What am I missing?

Update: The very strange thing is that if I change the time in the tq_get, to 2001:

```
A_stock_prices  <- tq_get("A",
                           get  = "stock.prices",
                           from = "2001-01-01",
                           to   = "2004-01-01")
```

I get the correct result for the year 2001 (but not for other years)..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your dataset is built but what's the first date for the 2001 group? Your manual attempt has it as January 2nd, 2001. If there's data present for January 1st, what's that result?

If that's not it, I'd recommend posting your data, just so we can see how it's structured.

Comment: Thanks! No, there is no data for the 1st of January. To obtain all the data you have to run these lines of code: A_stock_prices  <- tq_get("A",
                       get  = "stock.prices",
                       from = "2000-01-01",
                       to   = "2004-12-31")

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured it out:
tq_get() calculates the return for a "day before" the requested period.

I.e., for the yearly return it calculates the return from (say) 31/12/2022 to 31/12/2021 (rather than to 01/01/2022).